# Mysql 5.5.25a on windows is missing pager command

Tags: mysql, windows, pager

I am not sure if this is my particular installation of mysql 5.5.26a or if mysql has a different set of commands on windows machines. I do not work on windows machines and cannot find the pager/nopager command in mysql. Actually I am missing a few more commands (like edit, system, pager, nopager). Is this specific to mysql on windows?

I try to disable the standard output with pager > /dev/null. That is NOT working on the windows machine, but on two other servers I tested it on (Linux, Bsd). Does anybody know how to do that on mysql on a windows server? Any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: `/dev/null` doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: right, neither does pager as I just figured out:

--pager[=command]

Use the given command for paging query output. If the command is omitted, the default pager is the value of your PAGER environment variable. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename], and so forth. This option works only on Unix and only in interactive mode.

Is there another way to suppress stdout ind mysql on windows?

Comment: ok, just for future reference, I've found a workaround for my problem. Use INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options in the select statement to write the result into a file. BUT you cannot override an existing file which makes it a bit senseless for repetitive selects. 

In a procedure you can set a variable and write the result into that:
SET @VAR = '';
SELECT 1 INTO @VAR;

That will not print any output to the stdout just the
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

and that does the job for me...